# Powershell - Checking # of files in a folder across a domain

Tags: windows, powershell, fonts

So I'm trying to count the number of font files (that have different extensions) inside the local font folder of every computer in my domain at work to verify which computers have an up to date font installation using powershell.

So far I have

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count;
```

as a means of counting the files, I'm just at a loss on how exactly to replicate this and get a output that indicates the file count for the path for every computer on my domain (the file path is all the same for each)

How should I best proceed?

Comment: You'd have to query all computer names, if you don't already have them, then either use the UNC path to query the root folder, or use `Invoke-Command` (*preferred*) to get the results for you against all those machines.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the command against every computer. Assuming you have some sort of domain admin privelege and can access admin shares on all computers, you can use the c$ share.

The code below takes a list of computers in a single column CSV with no headers and runs the command against the admin share on each

```
$computers = Import-Csv -Path C:\computers.csv -Header Computer;

foreach($c in $computers)
{
    Write-Host (Get-ChildItem "\\$($c.Computer)\c$\MyFolder" | Measure-Object).Count;
};
```